# How can I remove these bash errors?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8. When I'm launching Terminal, I'm getting these messages.

How can I remove this error? I want get rid of this configuration from the bash profile.

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.s: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which files did you edit? `.bash_profile`? Or did you change anything in `profile.d`?

Comment: @slhck Sorry I dont remember:(

Comment: Do you have backups? Did you install RVM as multi-user (i.e. with `sudo`)? Can you start another shell by editing the Terminal preferences and executing `/bin/zsh` instead, for example? If so the culprit would be `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These entries are for Ruby Version Manager. Presumably this software has been removed, yet the offending statements remain in your /etc/profile - generating errors when you start Terminal.

Using your favourite editor and edit `/etc/profile`. Locate these lines-:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

and comment them out like this -:

```
# source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
# source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Comment: This would never be in `/etc/profile` unless the OP edited the file manually.

Comment: @MKK if the commands are not in /etc/profile then look in your home directory for the entries in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @suspectus Thanks so much:) It solved everything now:)